# How to Read all anchor tags from Raw html using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html

Here is my html string

```
string htmlData="<!DOCTYPE html><html><Head></Head><body>&lt;div&gt;&lt;a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://blender.palmbeachschools.org/GetFile.aspx?f=e9bf5637-c5bd-d4ba-3a1e-cf35ecfcad13\" style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: large;\"&gt;Breakdown of Standards by Unit &lt;/a&gt;&lt;span style=\"font-size: large; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</body></html>"
```

I have to read all the anchor tags from this html. the challenge here is all the anchor tags are not parsed.

I tried using

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();          
doc.LoadHtml(htmltemp);
var pre = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
```

It returned me null.

Answer (score 0):

```
       string htmlData = "<a href='1'>First</a><ul><li><a href='1'>Second</a></li><li><a href='1'>Third</a></li></ul>";
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

        doc.LoadHtml(htmlData);
        var anchorTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
```

You can use this code.